# Capturing Image in Android getting error on onActivityResult

Tags: java, android

I was trying to capture image in Android but I am getting error like:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                    Process: com.pace.planes, PID: 18741
>                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1888, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/images/media/4532 }} to activity {com.pace.planes/com.pace.planes.Confirmation}: java.lang.NullPointerException

While I used all suggested solutions over Stack Overflow. Here is my code:

```
captureImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
        }
    });
```

And here is onActivityResult code:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(resultCode != RESULT_CANCELED && data != null){

        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode== Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Bitmap imagebitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            Uri tempUri = getImageUri(getApplicationContext(), imagebitmap);
            // CALL THIS METHOD TO GET THE ACTUAL PATH
            finalFilePath = new File(getRealPathFromURI(tempUri));
            // imageBitmap = Compressor.getDefault(this).compressToBitmap(finalFilePath);
            captureImage.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            imagebitmap = new Compressor.Builder(this)
                .setQuality(10)
                .setCompressFormat(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG)
                .setDestinationDirectoryPath(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getAbsolutePath())
                .build()
                .compressToBitmap(finalFilePath);
            captureImage.setImageBitmap(imagebitmap);
            //set status image is seleted
            IsImageSelected = true;
        }
    }
}

public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
    String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
    return Uri.parse(path);
}

public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri uri) {
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
    return cursor.getString(idx);
}
```

Comment: resukt is in content:// format and you trying to getUri that's why it is happening i suggest you to use image croping library https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper

Comment: `NullPointerException`. Thats the problem. If you look further in the LogCat you will see which of your code line causes this exception. So then you know which pointer/variable is null.

Comment: `getImageUri()`. That is a complete wrong name as images or here Bitmaps have no uri. Your function is saving a bitmap to file. After that the file has an uri.